# Display textarea format on echo from database

Tags: php, mysql, format, echo

I have created a form

```
<form name="form1" method="post">
    <textarea rows="5" cols="20" name="ta1"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
    <textarea rows="5" cols="20"><?php echo $_POST['ta1']; ?></textarea>
</form>
```

And a PHP code

```
<?php
    if ($_POST['submit']) {
        $llo = $_POST['ta1'];
        $con1 = mysql_connect("localhost", "FreeUser", "123456");
        mysql_select_db("database", $con1);
        mysql_query("insert into test (ttta) values ('$llo')");
        $q1 = mysql_query("select * from test");
        $res = mysql_fetch_array($q1);
        echo $res['ttta'];
    }
?>
```

Database table test

```
id Auto_Increment
ttta mediumtext 500
```

only two fields in table

Now when i type something in textarea as formatted below

```
Rafee
Web Developer
XYZ Company
New York
```

When i press the submit button, same content with same formatting structure in stored / displayed in database table / textbox

But when i `echo` this value its displaying in single line without any format.
How can we achived this.

And i have added an image for better understanding

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use

```
echo nl2br($res['ttta']);
```

That will convert `\n` into the HTML tag `<br />`

In HTML, visible line brakes requires the use of the HTML tag `<br />`, but in your PHP, the stored data is `"Rafee\nWeb Developer\nXYZ Company\nNew York\n"`, so you need the function to turn `"\n"` into `"<br />"`.

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

Comment: Thanks, need more help on this..

Is there anything.. that will read each and every line of `echo nl2br($res['ttta']);` and stores into array

Comment: @Rafee Sorry I mistakenly swapped the two arguments, should be `$lines_array=explode("\n", $res['ttta']);`